# AmazonCloudWatch PutMetricData request format parsing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cloudwatch

How to parse PutMetricData Sample Request as show below.
I want to parse all the MetricData and stores the values in a struct in golang.

```
https://monitoring.&api-domain;/doc/2010-08-01/
?Action=PutMetricData
&Version=2010-08-01
&Namespace=TestNamespace
&MetricData.member.1.MetricName=buffers
&MetricData.member.1.Unit=Bytes
&MetricData.member.1.Value=231434333
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.1.Name=InstanceID
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.1.Value=i-aaba32d4
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.2.Name=InstanceType
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.2.Value=m1.small
&MetricData.member.2.MetricName=latency
&MetricData.member.2.Unit=Milliseconds
&MetricData.member.2.Value=23
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.1.Name=InstanceID
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.1.Value=i-aaba32d4
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.2.Name=InstanceType
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.2.Value=m1.small**
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Not able to understand this is in which format and how to parse it. Any library available to generate and parse this kind of formatted message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `newlines` that is a URL. Start with `url.Parse`, then use the `Query()` function to get access to the url parameters:

```golang
func main() {
    var input = `https://monitoring.&api-domain;/doc/2010-08-01/
?Action=PutMetricData
&Version=2010-08-01
&Namespace=TestNamespace
&MetricData.member.1.MetricName=buffers
&MetricData.member.1.Unit=Bytes
&MetricData.member.1.Value=231434333
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.1.Name=InstanceID
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.1.Value=i-aaba32d4
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.2.Name=InstanceType
&MetricData.member.1.Dimensions.member.2.Value=m1.small
&MetricData.member.2.MetricName=latency
&MetricData.member.2.Unit=Milliseconds
&MetricData.member.2.Value=23
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.1.Name=InstanceID
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.1.Value=i-aaba32d4
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.2.Name=InstanceType
&MetricData.member.2.Dimensions.member.2.Value=m1.small**
&AUTHPARAMS`
    // possibly also needs to replace \r
    input = strings.ReplaceAll(input, "\n", "")

    uri, err := url.Parse(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for key, val := range uri.Query() {
        fmt.Println(key, val)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4eqVnPH-H0D)

From here on out it's up to you how you want the target struct to look like.

Comment: can this be parse and stores in struct PutMetricDataInput using some library. I tried using gorilla schema but nested struct are not able to parse?

Comment: Found the solutions. we can use gorilla schema library to parse and stores it on struct .